# Theoretical writes/sec limit

Tags: sql-server, performance, monitoring

If I have solarwinds which has an alert set whenever we have more than 300 writes per second, and I know 300 writes per second is fine, and the writes per second often goes over 6500, how can I work out what the theoretical limit of writes per second is, so I can alter the alert thus making it actionable?

If "The number of writes should not exceed 85% of the disk capacity" how can I work out the number of writes that are possible with my current disk configuration?

Comment: I think you can test for this yourself: generate some load and determine at what level the system becomes unresponsive. But I would look elsewhere to see what processes causes the load and monitor those, possibly rate-limiting or queuing those.

Comment: What action are you going to perform when IO goes over 85% of the disk capacity?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this will be to monitor the writes/sec for weeks or a month and then come up with a number based on what the max values that you are seeing.  Obviously this is a rough guide, and as your workload changes you would have to adjust the threshold as well.

You could also use disk benchmarking tools to test the throughput of your disk subsystem.  [diskspd](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-A-Robust-Storage-6ef84e62) is something which we use.  Please also note that writes/sec is dependant on the block size that is used.  Based on what the drive is used for(data or transaction log)  and also based on the type of workload, SQL Server could use different.  You can read about SQL IO sizes [here](https://blog.purestorage.com/what-is-sql-servers-io-block-size/).  Obviously if you run this on a production system, you might have a performance impact.

A better performance counter to alert on would be `sec/Write` or `sec/Read`.  You can read about it [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-analyze-storage-subsystem-performance-in-sql-server/) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3214.monitoring-disk-usage.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

imho,

```
var jsonHDDiops = [
    { "n": '[HDD-15K]', "v":      175 },
    { "n": '[HDD-10K]', "v":      125 },
    { "n": '[HDD-7K2]', "v":      90 },
    { "n": '[HDD-5K9]', "v":      75 }
  ];
var jsonRAIDpenalty = [
    { "n": '[RAID 10]', "v":      2 },
    { "n": '[RAID DP]', "v":      2 },
    { "n": '[RAID 1]',  "v":      2 },
    { "n": '[RAID 0]',  "v":      1 },
    { "n": '[RAID 5]',  "v":      4 },
    { "n": '[RAID 6]',  "v":      6 } //?
  ];

 function dvFiops(RAIDtype,numberHDD,HDDtype,percentR,jsonHDDiops,jsonRAIDpenalty){
   if (percentR>100 || percentR<0) { return 0;}
   var percentW =100-percentR;
   var iops=0; var RAWiops=0; var Fiops=0;
   var RAIDpenalty=1;
   for (var ic = 0; ic < jsonHDDiops.length; ++ic) { 
     if(jsonHDDiops[ic].n === HDDtype) {iops = jsonHDDiops[ic].v;}
   }  
   for (var ic = 0; ic < jsonRAIDpenalty.length; ++ic) { 
     if(jsonRAIDpenalty[ic].n === RAIDtype) {RAIDpenalty = jsonRAIDpenalty[ic].v;}
   }  
   RAWiops=iops*numberHDD;
   Fiops= ((RAWiops*percentW/100)/RAIDpenalty)+(RAWiops*percentR/100);
   return Fiops;
   }
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS => edit jsonHDDiops value

85% write => percentR=15

P.S. Example:

[image: iops]